# I could not use the group name as the condition in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a little project and would like to create a small macro in VBA in Excel according to ChatGPT
The code are

```vb
Sub InsertShapeGroupBasedOnCondition()
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim condition As String
    Dim groupName As String
    Dim shapeExists As Boolean
    
    condition = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Operating").Range("C2").Value
    shapeExists = False
    
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("Z:\999 Program Drawing\Testformacro.xlsx")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks("Testformacro.xlsx") ' Check if it's already open
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If sourceWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        ' If not open, then open it
        On Error Resume Next
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("Z:\999 Program Drawing\Testformacro.xlsx") ' Replace with the full path to your source workbook
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    If sourceWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Source workbook not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
       
    Set targetWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Operating")

    Select Case condition
        Case "Rectangle"
            groupName = "Rectangle"
        Case "Door2fitting2holes"
            groupName = "Door2fitting2holes"
        Case "Door3fitting3holes"
            groupName = "Door3fitting3holes"
    
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Input condition not recognized."
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    For Each sourceSheet In sourceWorkbook.Sheets
        ' Check if the shape group exists in the current sheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim sourceShape As Shape
        Set sourceShape = sourceSheet(Doorwithfitting).Shapes(groupName) 
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not sourceShape Is Nothing Then
            ' Create a copy of the shape in the target workbook
            sourceShape.Copy
            targetWorkbook.Sheets("Operating").Range("H5").PasteSpecial ' Adjust the target sheet and cell as needed
            shapeExists = True
        End If
    Next sourceSheet

    ' Display a message if no grouped shapes were found
    If Not shapeExists Then
        MsgBox "No shape groups found in the source workbook for the specified condition."
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End Sub
```

However when I run the code with the correct condition, it shows that "No shape groups found in the source workbook for the specified condition" Could you help me solved the problem please?

Could you help me solved the problem please?

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` - then you will see that the code fails, as neither `Doorwithfitting` is set nor `sourceSheet(Dorrwithfitting)` is valid VBA.

Comment: As @Ike said.  Also `targetWorkbook` isn't defined - should probably be `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Thank for help both Ike and Daren, I have fixed the workbook as you said. Also, when I remove the on error resume next as Ike said, the code has failed at 
Set sourceShape = sourceSheet(Doorwithfitting).Shapes(groupName)
It said that the Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem is due to how you're attempting to access and verify for the existence of shape groups in the source worksheet. Let's make some changes to your code to guarantee it works properly:

```vb
Sub InsertShapeGroupBasedOnCondition()
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim condition As String
    Dim groupName As String
    Dim shapeExists As Boolean
    
    ' Get the condition from the "Operating" sheet of the current workbook
    condition = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Operating").Range("C2").Value
    shapeExists = False
    
    ' Define the name of the group in the source workbook based on the condition
    Select Case condition
        Case "Rectangle"
            groupName = "Rectangle"
        Case "Door2fitting2holes"
            groupName = "Door2fitting2holes"
        Case "Door3fitting3holes"
            groupName = "Door3fitting3holes"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Input condition not recognized."
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    ' Try to open the source workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks("Testformacro.xlsx")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If sourceWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        ' If not open, then open it
        On Error Resume Next
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("Z:\999 Program Drawing\Testformacro.xlsx")
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    If sourceWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Source workbook not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
       
    ' Set the target worksheet in the current workbook
    Set targetWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Operating")

    ' Loop through all sheets in the source workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    For Each sourceSheet In sourceWorkbook.Sheets
        ' Check if the shape group exists in the current sheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim sourceShape As Shape
        Set sourceShape = sourceSheet.Shapes(groupName) ' Use Shapes method to access shapes
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not sourceShape Is Nothing Then
            ' Create a copy of the shape in the target worksheet
            sourceShape.Copy
            targetWorksheet.Range("H5").PasteSpecial ' Adjust the target sheet and cell as needed
            shapeExists = True
        End If
    Next sourceSheet

    ' Display a message if no grouped shapes were found
    If Not shapeExists Then
        MsgBox "No shape groups found in the source workbook for the specified condition."
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Please ensure that the condition in cell C2 of the "Operating" sheet corresponds to one of the conditions indicated in the `Select Case` statement. The source workbook "Testformacro.xlsx" is present in the directory supplied.

Comment: Yep it is working and I could copy/paste the group of shape now. Thank you for the Help

Comment: Could I ask you something? I have used the code and it works correctly however there are multiple copy that were pasted in the same place. Could you help me fixed it please?